# Reverse Ajax + Spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, reverse, dwr

I have very unique requirement in my web apps. I have two web apps for eg. webapp1 and webapp2. In webapp1 we are gathering some info and pass it to webapp2. Webapp2 process this info and when complete, has to inform back to webapp1 that all data are processed either successfully or not. Now I know what if there is one web app then I can use dwr reverse ajax and it can send the update back to page. Can we use DWR in my scenario too? Also I dont want to broadcast message to all opened webapp1 instead to only webapp1(browser), who send data to webapp2.

I hope I have clearly explained the scenario

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a messaging system like JMS (or possibly just a REST style web service) to communicate between the two apps. Then the browser just communicates with webapp1 using DWR.

Comment: If I use activemq ajax features, how does it perform. Because the time taken by webapp2 to process data submitted by webapp1 is not consistent

Answer (score 0):

You can use Atmosphere framework and inbuilt websocket for such scenario.

Atmosphere framework are easy to integrate with spring MVC.